# Why doesn't 12th month execute properly?

Tags: java

```
String months[] = { null , "Jan" , "Feb" , "Mar" , "Apr", 
                    "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
                    "Nov", "Dec" };

try
{
  System.out.print("Enter month <1 for Jan - 12 for Dec>:  ");

  m = input.nextInt();
  MonthData();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Invalid month!"); //error message to  inform user of wrong input
}   

break;

static void MonthData()
{            

  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
  System.out.println(months[m]+" Expenditure <max 10 items>");

  try
  {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter item "+(i+1)+" <Press ENTER to exit> : ");
      monthItems[m][i] = input.next();

      if (monthItems[m][i].length() == 0)
      {
        return;
      } 
      else 
      {
        System.out.print("Enter amount : $");
        amount[m][i] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("");
      }   

    }

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("");
  }   
}
```

Hi Everyone

Just would like to say this code had a bit of help.But my question is why doesn't the function for December execute properly.

For example, when I clicked on the 12th month it just skips the function and ends the program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe, to help you we need the function/logic which calls this method. All of your data constructs are defined some where's else. This may be why you're having trouble, you're looking in the wrong place for the problem. Also you should use a try/catch block to determine your error.

Comment: WTB proper indentation and formatting while you are at it.

Comment: My first guess would be that monthItems is defined as double[12] and then you try to access monthItems[12]. But as Agnew says, you really need to display the exception. There's no point guessing when Java will just tell you.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why, but the following:

```
catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

won't print your exception 'e' and thus you're not going to get a clear idea of what's going on.

At the very least:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

will most likely give you a lot more info as to what's happening and is good practise generally (you can use logging frameworks etc but the principle remains the same).

Comment: Correct. OP should not swallow exceptions.

Comment: I would say at the very least, System.out.println(e.toString()). A stack trace would be more than that so it's not the "very least"!

Answer (score 2):

maybe its because you have declared an array of size 12 and access the last element of it with index 12 but it should be 11 since you start counting at 0 ... December = Month 11

Comment: static String months[] =
        { null , "Jan" , "Feb" , "Mar" , "Apr", "May",
        "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
        "Nov", "Dec" };                                                               This is my code for storing the months